# Stripe API, localize product prices based on location

Tags: stripe-payments

Is it possible to have localized prices for Stripe products? I've been searching for a while and couldn't find anything in the docs related to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note : Sometime in Aug 2022, Stripe launched Multi-currency Prices which you can read about here : https://stripe.com/docs/products-prices/pricing-models#multicurrency

[old answer]
A price’s currency is set at the time of its creation and can’t be changed. To offer the same price in multiple currencies, you have to create separate prices.  For example, you could have Product prod_A that has price_1 for €2.00 / month, price_2 for US$20.00 / month.

You can read more about it in detail here :

- https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/products-and-prices#working-with-local-currencies
- https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/create#create_price-currency

Comment: But can I offer different amounts based on different currencies? For example, if someone is in Thailand, I want to charge them 30% less than I charge people in the US for the same product and subscription package

Comment: Yes, you can offer different amounts based on different currencies. You would create a Price for each currency. For example, you could have Product prod_A that has price_1 for €2.00 / month, price_2 for US$20.00 / month.

Comment: I understand, I had a look at the API and it clarified it for me as well, do you want to make add an answer so that I may accept it as the correct one?

Comment: Just to clarify for any future readers, showing specific plans based on user location on the client-side will have to be handled through your own logic